# Input contains a paragraph character that needs to be removed

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have been attempting to modify the text of the parent element from within the xsl. How can I delete the

element from the XSL code ( I do not control the input ).  I only want to delete the preceding line break not all line breaks in the body.  The preceding 'some text here' may take the form of multiple paragraphs.

**Xsl**

```
<xsl:template match="element">
  <!-- attempting to add fix here -->

  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

**Input**

```
<body>
  <p>
    some text here
  </p>
  <element>
    some more text
  </element>
</body>
```

**Output**

```
some text here
some more text
```

**Desired Output**

```
some text here some more text
```

Comment: Do you want to create plain text with your XSLT? And is all you want the removal of line breaks? Also please fix the XSLT code sample as ` <xsl:apply-templates /">` is not proper XML syntax.

Comment: @martin the body is wrapped as a whole by html elements already. The 'element' contains sub elements that all simplify down to plain text.  I know how I'd add the elements together, just not sure how to get rid of that single line break.  As I edited in my description.  I don't want to remove all breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
<xsl:template match="p[following-sibling::*[1][self::element]]//text() | element[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]//text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

do what you want?

You don't need the `<xsl:template match="element"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>` as the built-in template will do that anyway.

I found some time to test code, now I have

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="p[following-sibling::*[1][self::element]]//text() |
  element[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]]//text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p] and following-sibling::*[1][self::element] and not(normalize-space())]">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms

```
<body>
  <p>
    some text here
  </p>
  <element>
    some more text
  </element>
</body>
```

into

```
  some text here some more text
```

Comment: That seems closer to what I am looking for.  I'll fiddle around with it a bit and let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'm accepting this answer because normalize-space() is what I need to use.  It doesn't solve my overarching problem but does solve this piece.  Thanks again :)